# How to handle uncertain Json using Java Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

I got this question today from a fellow colleague. Let's say we got a Json String like this one:

```
{people:{name:Carlos}}
```

So I got a simple class to handle this Json String, wich will look something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
class PeopleHandler(){

    public Person people;

}
```

It happens that sometime the Json String will provide a list of persons, like this:

```
{people:[{name:Carlos}, {name:Michel}]}
```

My question is: how can I change my PeopleHandler class to manage this kind of inputs, is there any annotation that can help?

**NOTE**: the main problem is that I can receive any of the Json String exampled here. So my class must be able to support both.

**NOTE 2**: I don't have control over the input, it is given by a web service. I know I could check the Json and build a copy with list whenever there is a single object, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [**JsonDeserialize**](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonDeserialize.html) annotaion and addition deserializer.
**PeopleHandler.java**

```
public class PeopleHandler 
{
   private List<Person> people;

   @JsonDeserialize(using = PersonDeserializer.class)
   public void setPeople(List<Person> o)
   {
      people = o;
   }

}
```

**PersonDeserializer.java**

```
public class PersonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Person>>
{
   @Override
   public List<Person> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
   {
      List<Person> retVal = new ArrayList<Person>();
      if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT)
      {
         retVal.add(jp.readValueAs(Person.class));
      }
      else if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY)
      {
         while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT)
         {
            retVal.add(jp.readValueAs(Person.class));
         }
      }

      return retVal;
   }
}
```

Comment: Will this work when the json i recieve is just an objet, like:
    {people:{name:Carlos}}
?

Comment: @cgajardo no, only for array

Comment: see, that's my problem here :(

Comment: Why can't you have a list of one Person?

Comment: I don't have control over the input and whenever there is a single object the service will response with only the object (not the array)

Comment: I'll try this one, it seems like a very good solution. Once I do that I'll mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you've got there is actually an "array" of JSON objects.  Hence, you might try making PeopleHandler use ArrayList< People> people;